# Cannot convert type `ObjectPool<T>' to `ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>'

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a simple ObjectPool implementation. The ObjectPool holds a stack of ObjectPoolObjects. ObjectPoolObject is an abstract class that defines two methods. I am trying to add a reference to the parent pool to the ObjectPoolObject class. I got to work by using the curiously recurring template pattern, but then i couldnt derive from a class that was already deriving from ObjectPoolObject. (ie, grenade inherits from bullet which inherits from ObjectPoolObject)...

So anyways, the parent pool is held by the ObjectPoolObject like so: ObjectPool m_parent... but I cant seem to set m_parent = this; in the ObjectPool class... It seems like I definetly should be able to. I dont want to have to cast to object and then cast to ObjectPool.. it seems like I should safely be able to do this:

```
public abstract class ObjectPoolObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public abstract void ObjectPool_Activate();
    public abstract void ObjectPool_Deactivate();

    public ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject> m_pool;
}


public class ObjectPool<T> where T : ObjectPoolObject
{
    public ObjectPool(CreateObjectDelegate creationMethod)
    {
        m_creationMethod = creationMethod;
        T objectPoolObject = creationMethod();
        // this is the line that gives me error CS0030: Cannot convert type `ObjectPool<T>' to `ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>'
        objectPoolObject.m_pool = this;
    }
}
```

Since T : ObjectPoolObject I should be able to do this...

All I need is for the ObjectPoolObject to have a reference to it's parent ObjectPool... how can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

This is the error message:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type ObjectPool<T> to ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>'
```

but since T: ObjectPoolObject it seems like it should be able to do this. its like it's saying "cannot convert a child class to a parent class..." T inherits from ObjectPoolObject... thus ObjectPool of T is analogous to a child class ObjectPool of ObjectPoolObject... Liskov substitution principle should allow me to cast a ObjectPool of T to an ObjectPool of ObjectPoolObject.

For example, I have an ObjectPool of Bullets where Bullet inherits from ObjectPoolObject. I should be able to cast it to an ObjectPool of ObjectPoolObjects, considering all the elements in the ObjectPool are ObjectPoolObjects.....

EDIT - I'm starting to understand what the problem with the cast is.... its so hard to explain, wow.

EDIT2 - The answer of defining an interface using the "in" keyword on the generic type is the correct answer for this problem. HOWEVER! I have decided that this has crossed the line of "too complex" and have decided to remove the m_pool field from the ObjectPoolObject. When you get an object from an object pool, its up to you to record which pool it came from and put it back appropriately. The m_pool field was simply dirtying up my system too much for me to justify including it.

Removing the Genericism from ObjectPool completely is also a functional solution, but it requires me to cast the return result of every ObjectPool.Get call, and I decided I didn't want that either.

Comment: No, just because T is (or inherits from) ObjectpoolObject doesn't mean that ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject> is ( or inherits from) ObjectPool<T>

Comment: this is ObjectPool<T> where T : ObjectPoolObject....

I should be able to cast this to ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>...

I think you have the second part of your sentence backwards. I'm T is an ObjectPoolObject...

Comment: I don't think so? You are trying to assign m_pool (which is a ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>) with a variable that is a ObjectPool<T> where T is or inherits from ObjectPoolObject.

Again, the issue is noth wether T inherits from ObjectPoolObject but wether ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject> inherits from ObjectPool<T> (because thats what you are assuming when trying to assign m_pool)

Comment: I dont see how there is a conflict. I am not trying to cast ObjectPoolObject to T. I'm doing the opposite. The error states: "Cannot convert type `ObjectPool<T>' to `ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>'". I should be able to convert ObjectPool<T> to ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject> since T : ObjectPoolObject.

Comment: Yeah, im working on an answer, but am not ready yet :P

Comment: `ObjectPool<T>` is not convertible to `ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>` for the same reason that `List<Giraffe>` is not convertible to `List<Animal>`.  You'll end up with lions in the giraffe pen.

Comment: A List of Giraffes is a List of Animals, though. Giraffes are animals

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your type parameter contravariant using the `in` modifier, which is only allowed on interfaces and delegates.

```
interface IObjectPool<in T> where T : ObjectPoolObject
{

}

class ObjectPoolObject
{
    public IObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject> Pool { get; internal set; }
}

class ObjectPool<T> : IObjectPool<T> where T : ObjectPoolObject
{
    public ObjectPool(Func<T> createObject)
    {
        T obj = createObject();
        obj.Pool = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you! I knew it was doable. I need the "in" keyword, not the "out" keyword, however, since I need the "Store" method of the interface which takes the T as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at covariance and contravariance in C# as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

In short - you need to declare your class as

```
public class ObjectPool<**in** T> where T : ObjectPoolObject
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while T does indeed inherit from ObjectPoolObject, that hos nothing to do wether ObjectPool<T> inherits from ObjectPool<ObjectPoolObject>.

for example, take the following code:

```
public class Class1<T> where T : Class3, new()
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Class3 variable1;
        variable1 = new T(); // This works just fine T is or inherits from Class3

        Class1<Class3> variable3;
        variable3 = new Class1<Class2>(); // This will not work, while Class2 does indeed inherit from Class3,
                                          // Class1<Class2> is still a different class from Class1<Class3>
                                          // while their type parameters have an inheritance between them, they themselves do not.

        Class1<Class3> variable2;
        variable2 = new Class1<T>(); // And for just the same reason as stated above, this will not work either
    }
}
```

To do what you're trying to do, we would have to make something more complex (and to be honest, complexity is not Always a good thing). But just for the sake of it, have a look at this:

```
public class AbstractObjectPool<T, T2> where T : AbstractObjectPool<T, T2> where T2 : ObjectPoolObject<T, T2>
{
    public T m_pool;
}

public class ObjectPool<T> : AbstractObjectPool<ObjectPool<T>, T> where T : ObjectPoolObject<ObjectPool<T>, T>
{
    public ObjectPool(Func<ObjectPool<T>> creationMethod)
    {
        ObjectPool<T> objectPoolObject = creationMethod();
        objectPoolObject.m_pool = this;
    }
}

public abstract class ObjectPoolObject<T, T2> where T : AbstractObjectPool<T, T2> where T2 : ObjectPoolObject<T, T2>
{

}
```

However, I wonder if (in your case) you wouldn't be better off skipping generics alltogeather and co for a simple base class:

```
public class ObjectPool
{
    public ObjectPool(Func<ObjectPoolObject> creationMethod)
    {
        ObjectPoolObject objectPoolObject = creationMethod();
        objectPoolObject.m_pool = this;
    }
}

public abstract class ObjectPoolObject
{
    public ObjectPool m_pool;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I use the Generic in the ObjectPool in one very convenient way, and I suppose that I can change that convenience in order to gain the parent reference I desire...

Your answer essentially boils down to this: "// This will not work, while Class2 does indeed inherit from Class3,
                                          // Class1<Class2> is still a different class from Class1<Class3>
                                          // while their type parameters have an inheritance between them, they themselves do not."

Can you help me understand why?

Comment: I think I will move away from using Generics in the ObjectPool class....

Comment: As to the why: When the compiler JITs your code for Class1<Class2> and Class1<Class3>, it produces two different types that are used, which do not share any inheritance between one another (sort of like if you had manually created two classes named Class1ForClass2 and Class1ForClass3). In this case it's easy to see that there is no reason for Class1ForClass3 to be castable to or from Class1ForClass2.

But the code between those two classes will be shared by the JIT, i.e. same code, different types.